# Saxon can't find class in Windows app, does fine in command line

Tags: saxon, xerces, ikvm

What we're doing is a little weird. We use the Java Saxon in .NET by compiling it using IKVM along with all of our other Java code. In the command line app it works great.

But using all this in our Windows forms app, we get:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message (System.Exception)=SAX2 driver class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser not found
  Message=SAX2 driver class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser not found
  Source (System.Exception)=IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API
  Source=IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API
  StackTrace (System.Exception)=   at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(ClassLoader , String )
   at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()
   at net.windward.datasource.xml.SaxonDataSource.ctor(InputStream xmlData, InputStream schemaFile, Boolean preserveWhiteSpace)
  StackTrace:
       at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(ClassLoader , String )
       at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()
       at net.windward.datasource.xml.SaxonDataSource.ctor(InputStream xmlData, InputStream schemaFile, Boolean preserveWhiteSpace)
  InnerException:
```

Clearly the problem is com.sun.org.* is no where to be found in the IKVM created DLL. What's weird to me is the command line app works, not that the forms app fails.

The question is, what do I do to include com.sun.org.* in the IKVM-ed DLL?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `com.sun.org.apache.xerces` is present in the Oracle JDK but not in OpenJDK, and the IKVM library is based on OpenJDK. You should probably be using the JAXP mechanisms (`SAXParserFactory` or `XMLReaderFactory`) to obtain an `XMLReader` rather than trying to load a specific implementation class.

**LATER**

OK, it seems from the stack trace that you're calling XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader() to get a parser. The JDK 1.8 version of that method appears to do:

(a) get the value of system property `org.xml.sax.driver`.

(b) look in META-INF/services

(c) use class `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser`

I don't know if the IKVM version of the method is the same: it would a bit odd to retain the com.sun.org fallback if that parser isn't actually in the runtime. But there are plenty of ways of getting a different XMLReader (including instantiating it directly, ignoring the factory methods).

Comment: We're not doing anything to specify the reader/parser as far as I know. Is there something we should set when we're running under .NET where we've IKVMed saxon9ee.jar?

Comment: What do you suggest is best for us to do where our Java code runs in both Java and via IKVM, in .NET? thanks

Comment: Michael - how do you suggest we get an XMLReader? And it's fine if Java & .NET should be different. thanks.

Comment: I would try instantiating Apache Xerces either directly in the code or by setting the `org.xml.sax.driver` system property to `org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser`

Comment: Michael - what I'm struggling with on this is it works fine in our run-time. On some builds it works fine in our Forms based Office add-in. It presently works fine in both but we get this problem in our unit tests. Why all this weirdness? And best as I can tell we don't have Xerces in our code. Also, how do you handle this in your .NET version - anything special or do you just build it all against IKVM? TIA

Comment: The DLLs for Saxon/.NET include Apache Xerces cross-compiled using IKVM. We give users a choice of using the Xerces parser or the Microsoft .NET parser. We mainly use Xerces because the Microsoft .NET parser doesn't report ID attributes, which causes any stylesheet using id() to fail.

Comment: Is there anything else we should add on the .NET side in addition to Xerces? We are adding all the standard IKVM DLLs. And what version of Xerces are you using? thanks

Comment: I think we should probably take this discussion elsewhere, following SO guidelines.